# What are black frames around app screen?

Tags: ios

What causes the black frame around certain apps? When running several popular apps that were created a few years a go, i notice a small black frame that contains the actually view in the app (like a movie when you see it in theaters only the bars go around the view completely) what is this called?

Answer (score 1):

It means they weren't optimized for 4-inch screens.

Comment: should code be used to eliminate this effect? I wonder why some of the big social networking apps still have/allow this...

Comment: What *specific* apps do you mean?

Comment: I think they both were updated long ago. Did you update them?